# Multiple Combobox Search using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

I want to search data from a database where I am using 3 different comboBox.

I want to click the search button and after clicking I want the data to appear in all of the select comboBoxes.

The data should appear exactly as from the 3 comboBox that I have select. so how can I do this? thanks for the help.

Now, I use if else but I want to change them like I said above.

```
  private void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\acap\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();

        if (comboBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT No_ic as [I/C No.], Name as [Name], Program as [Program], No_Matric as [Matric No.], No_HP as [Handphone No.], Address as [Address], State as [State], Kohort as [Kohort] FROM Student where Program LIKE '" + comboBox1.Text + "%' ", con);
            sda.Fill(ds);

        }
        else if (comboBox2.Text.Length > 0)
        {

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT No_ic as [I/C No.], Name as [Name], Program as [Program], No_Matric as [Matric No.], No_HP as [Handphone No.], Address as [Address], State as [State], Kohort as [Kohort] FROM Student where State LIKE '" + comboBox2.Text + "%' ", con);
            sda.Fill(ds);
        }
        else if (comboBox3.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT No_ic as [I/C No.], Name as [Name], Program as [Program], No_Matric as [Matric No.], No_HP as [Handphone No.], Address as [Address], State as [State], Kohort as [Kohort] FROM Student where Kohort LIKE '" + comboBox3.Text + "%' ", con);
            sda.Fill(ds);
        }
```

Comment: What do you want query?

Comment: I just edit my code and question above. @Krishna

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach for this you would need to dynamically combine the conditions you've selected.

```
String query = "SELECT No_ic as [I/C No.], Name as [Name], Program as [Program], No_Matric as [Matric No.], No_HP as [Handphone No.], Address as [Address], State as [State], Kohort as [Kohort] FROM Student";
List<String> conditions = new List<String>();
if (comboBox1.Text.Length > 0)
{
    conditions.Add("Program LIKE '" + comboBox1.Text + "%' ");
}
if (comboBox2.Text.Length > 0)
{
    conditions.Add("State LIKE '" + comboBox2.Text + "%' ");
}
if (comboBox3.Text.Length > 0)
{
    conditions.Add("Kohort LIKE '" + comboBox3.Text + "%' ");
}

if (conditions.Count > 0)
{
    query = query + " WHERE " + String.Join(" AND ", conditions.ToArray())
}
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
sda.Fill(ds);
```